# Firebase 2.0・Query Users for Username from UISearchField・Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, uisearchbar, firebase-realtime-database

Im implementing a search box is my swift application that searches my firebase database for accounts that match their username.

my database structure is

> "users" {
>
> > "uid" {
> >
> > > "first_name" : "Bob",
> > >
> > > > "last_name" : "Someone"
> > > >
> > > > > "username" : "bobby"
> > > > >
> > > > > > }
> > > > > >
> > > > > > > }

(Sorry for block quotes i could get it to look good)
My problem is that i need to search for peoples usernames not and to do this i need to have my database path as

```
Database.child("users").child(uid!)
```

and then i can see the data.

I need to be able to search for a users username without having to set the path with their UID

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Firebase 2.x and 3.x

Since you mentioned that you are using firebase 2.0 you should be looking into [firebase legacy documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html) for `orderedByChild()` combined with `queryEqualToValue()`. Either way, searching in the new firebase docs you will see that nothing changed in terms of [Sorting and Filtering Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) and so you will still be using the same call in both versions.

```
ref.child("users").queryOrderedByChild("username").queryEqualToValue(username).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
    if let username = snapshot.value["username"] as? String {
        print("UID: \(snapshot.key) Username: \(username)")
    }
})
```